# Are we allowed to multiply a denominator that has a variable with zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I was given a question that resulted in the following equation:

$$ \cos(90°) = \frac{-10 + p}{\sqrt{11} \cdot \sqrt{20+p}}$$
Since $\cos(90°) = 0$, the equation becomes:
$$ 0 = \frac{-10 + p}{\sqrt{11} \cdot \sqrt{20+p}}$$

Wouldn't multiplying the denominator in this case cause us to lose roots? Can someone please elaborate on this – when can we do what?

Answer (score 3):

For $0=a/b$, the only solutions have $a=0, b\ne 0$.  By multiplying to get $0=a$, you do not lose roots.  You may **gain** roots if it could happen that $a=b=0$.

For example, $0=x/x$ has no solution, but multiplying by $x$ we get $0=x$, which does have a solution.

Comment: Okay, so if $b ≠ 0$, how can $a=b=0$ ? How would I gain a solution?

Comment: $0=x$ has solution $x$, which is not a solution of the original equation.  That is what I mean when I say we gained a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator does not contribute anything towards the roots of this function. You just have to look at the numerator and make sure it falls in the domain.

Note that $\sqrt 11\times \sqrt {20+p}$ will become invalid if $p\le-20$. Hence the domain of $p$ is $(-20,\infty)$. Equating the numerator to zero, we get $p=10$. As this value falls within the domain of $p$, it is the correct and only valid root of this expression.

Comment: "The denominator does not contribute anything towards the roots of this function." How do I know something does or doesn't contribute to the function?

Comment: Like GEdgar said, a fraction can only be equal to zero if the **numerator** is zero. The denominator does not matter as long as **it** itself is not zero. In simple terms, you can simply multiply both sides by $\sqrt 11\cdot\sqrt{20+p}$ and lose no roots.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a fraction
$$\frac{a}{b}=0$$
then if we multiply everything by $b$ we get $a=0$
So, when a fraction is equal to $0$, then effectively the denominator becomes irrelevant.